# Can I change the space bar behaviour in LyX math mode?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

When typing an equation in LyX math mode, pressing the space bar will sometimes exit the equation. This is annoying because I will often press it by accident. Sometimes I am typing fast and I immediately press backspace, which deletes my entire equation.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to disable this space bar behaviour in LyX 2.2.1?
2. Is there a way for the backspace key to delete the last
   symbol/element in the equation instead of the *entire* equation?

I have looked in "Preferences" but didn't find any relevant options. Perhaps there is an under-the-hood solution...?

EDIT: it looks like someone has tried something similar:
http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~hartkes/computer/lyx/lyx.php. Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble making heads or tails out of it.

EDIT: cross-posted at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=28474

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I don't think there is a way to change the behavior as you would like. This is the first time I've seen this request for LyX. It does sound very frustrating though!

Comment: Considering @scottkosty's comment, barring messing about with the sourcecode and compiling LyX yourself, you likely don't have any other options than posting a feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome (For what it's worth, while I don't use LyX, I've actually been annoyed by the space bar exiting math mode myself, when making an example related to a question here on site.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in LyX to do what you want so we need to edit the source code and recompile. Here is a patch that makes it so space does not exit math:

```
diff --git a/src/mathed/InsetMathNest.cpp b/src/mathed/InsetMathNest.cpp
index 3460cdc..9c102dc 100644
--- a/src/mathed/InsetMathNest.cpp
+++ b/src/mathed/InsetMathNest.cpp
@@ -921,14 +921,8 @@ void InsetMathNest::doDispatch(Cursor & cur, FuncRequest & cmd)
        // spacial handling of space. If we insert an inset
        // via macro mode, we want to put the cursor inside it
        // if relevant. Think typing "\frac<space>".
-       if (cmd.argument()[0] == ' '
-           && cur.inMacroMode() && cur.macroName() != "\\"
-           && cur.macroModeClose() && cur.pos() > 0) {
-           MathAtom const atom = cur.prevAtom();
-           if (atom->asNestInset() && atom->isActive()) {
-               cur.posBackward();
-               cur.pushBackward(*cur.nextInset());
-           }
+       if (cmd.argument()[0] == ' ') {
+           // do nothing
        } else if (!interpretChar(cur, cmd.argument()[0])) {
            cmd = FuncRequest(LFUN_FINISHED_FORWARD);
            cur.undispatched();
```

If you happen to be on Ubuntu (or other Linux), compiling LyX is easy and I can help you. If you are on Windows or Mac it is possible but much more complicated.

Disclaimer: this patch probably breaks something, but it worked for me in limited testing.